# django many to many query not giving user

Tags: python, django, view, many-to-many

I have models :

```
class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')
    answers = models.ManyToManyField('Answer',related_name='answer_name', blank=True)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)                     

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Answer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    ans_body = models.TextField()
    comments = models.ManyToManyField('Comment',related_name='answer_name', blank=True)
    count = models.IntegerField()
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.ans_body
```

and my view for submitting answer is :

```
ques = Question.objects.get(id=pk)
cpk = ques.category.id
anstext = request.GET.get('ans_body',False)

if request.user.is_doctor:
    for ansr in ques.answer_set.all():
        some = ansr.user.username
        print some
         if not request.user.username in some:
            ans = Answer()
            ans.user = request.user
            ans.question = ques
            ans.ans_body = anstext
            ans.save()
            messages.success(request, "Your answer has been posted successfully.")
            return redirect("question-detail", pk, cpk)
        else:
            messages.warning(request, "You cannot answer twice. Please use comment.")
            return redirect("question-detail", pk, cpk)
else:
    messages.warning(request, "You are not allowed to answer")
    return redirect("question-detail", pk, cpk)
```

I dont have any problems in submitting the answers it works perfect. Here I only want all the users that have given answers.

When I print 'some' it only gives the first user that has submitted answer but I want all the user.

How can I get all the users?? What will be the many to many query. What am I doing wrong??

When I do `for ansr in ques.answer_set.all():` it says view didnt return HttpResponseObject it returned none instead...
Any solution??

Comment: Are you sure the question `ques` has multiple answers? And why you are using `ManyToManyField` when you already have a `Question` `ForeignKey` in answer model?

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing `ques.answers.all()` instead of `ques.answer_set.all()`? And is `user.is_doctor` a method or attribute?

Comment: http://goo.gl/wpsq7s ... follow @AamirAdnan 's comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is really bad in handling the use case of multiple answers by a user, something like this should work for you:

```
ques = Question.objects.get(id=pk)
anstext = request.GET.get('ans_body',False)

if request.user.is_doctor:
    if ques.answer_set.filter(user__id=request.user.id).exists():
        messages.warning(request, "You cannot answer twice. Please use comment.")
    else:
        ans = Answer.objects.create(user=request.user, question=ques, ans_body=anstext)
        messages.success(request, "Your answer has been posted successfully.")
else:
    messages.warning(request, "You are not allowed to answer")
return redirect("question-detail", pk, ques.category.id)
```

Though this is still a bad approach, you should use [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/)

Comment: ohk when I do ques.answer_set.all() and print the user that has answered the question it only prints one user.

Comment: Its because in your code the forloop returns an `HttpResponse` in first iteration. It never get a chance to go to second iteration. And if a Question has no answer, then you will get error `view didn't return HttpResponseObject it returned none instead` because you are not handling that case. In any way your code is all mess and bugy, try my solution instead.